# iPhone 4s iOS 7.1.2

Tags: ios

It won't let me update past iOS 7.1.2 it keeps saying current software is up to date and I know that there is another update but how do I do it exactly?

Comment: You certain it's a 4S? The iPhone 4 can only use up to iOS 7.1.2, the 4S up to current, iOS 9.2.1 at present.

Answer (score 1):

My iPhone 4s is running iOS 9.2.1, so yes, there is another update.  If Software Update on the iPhone isn't working, maybe try updating it through iTunes?